# Prevent before_create method to save when false or nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `:before_create` method that performs some checks and returns `false` or `true`.

```
def create_subscription_on_gateway 
  gateway = self.keyword.shortcode.provider
  create_subscription = gateway.classify.constantize.new.create_subscription(self.phone,self.keyword_keyword,self.shortcode_shortcode,self.country)
  errors[:base] << "An error has occurred when finding gateway." if gateway.nil?
  errors[:base] << "No gateway found for this shortcode." if create_subscription.nil?
  errors[:base] << "Subscription could not be made." if create_subscription == false
end
```

Now, if the method returns `false` or `nil` I can see the errors on the form page okay. The problem is that the object has been saved to the database.

How can I prevent the object to be saved when there are still errors associated on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about, instead of a before_create, you use validations. And then change your create_subscription_on_gateway to a before_validation

```
validate :gateway_presence
validate :gateway_found
validate :create_subscription

def gateway_presence
  if # ...your code here
    errors.add(:gateway, "An error has occured..."
  end
end

def gateway_found
  if # ...your code here
    errors.add(:gateway, "An error has occured..."
  end
end
```

and so on...

Answer (score 10):

You can raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid exception, it will prevent model from being saved and won't break save flow.

```
if error?
 errors[:base] << "error"    
 raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(self)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

on before_create you could do:

```
def before_create_func
  errors.add(:base, "error message")
  throw :abort
end
```

this will add the error and also prevent record from saving.